# Tahoma text doesn't look smooth

Tags: html, css, text, fonts, smoothing

I'm using the Tahoma font for my website's logo, and it doesn't look smooth, anti-aliased, like it does in my design on GIMP. Anyone know of ways to make HTML text look better, or am I going to have to just go with an image?

Also, could someone explain to me why text looks this way in HTML, and why it never seems like it looked this way on other peoples websites?

Comment: learn about anti-aliasing http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Font_rasterization.  Then, make sure you have up to date browsers, because they have gotten better (as far as Windows goes) in the past few years.

Comment: I changed my windows settings from cleartype to standard. This helps with large text like logos, but diminishes small text like what's in this textarea that I'm currently typing in.

Comment: @Jonathan, yes I do. Sorry, I got the name mixed up.

Comment: @Sam Which version of which browser, on which version of operating system, does it look bad in? Could you provide a minimal example of code which demonstrates the problem? Try stripping down your HTML and CSS to the bare minimum needed to demonstrate that the text looks bad, and post that minimal example here to get more help.

Comment: I'm using Chrome 6, Windows Vista. The HTML is just an H1 with a font-size set to 40px. And here's what I see: http://img64.imageshack.us/img64/8427/fooc.jpg

Answer (score 3):

Go with an image.  You don't want your logo to look lousy.

But why does it look so bad for you?  Assuming you're looking at your own design with the same setup (browser, OS) that you use for normal browsing, it's most likely that you just don't notice it for other sites.  Your brain can do tricky things when you put on your designer/artist hat.  I find that my normal web browsing mindset tends to be a lot more forgiving of things like pixelated text.

Comment: An image is much better than fiddling with proper em sizes

Comment: There are lots of good places for live text.  Your logo is not one of them.

Comment: It's for a wordpress theme, so when I say logo, I actually meant the blog name.